# Get the original data format of a DataColumn

Tags: .net, sql, database, datacolumn

How can I get the original data format (in the database) of a DataColumn object?

I have DataColumn objects from a DataTable that is part of the result of opening a DBCommand SQL "select" query.

How do I get information on the original data formats returned by the query (i.e. "varchar[50]" and so forth).

I know DataColumn.DataType but the information here is not specific enough, for example it is not possible to distinguish varchar and char or to distinguish date and timestamp or to get the maximum length of a varchar field and so on.

Getting information from the server database scheme directly is not the solution I am looking for, because the query text is entered by the user and I don't want to parse the text myself to find out what column of what table is being used and because there can be columns that don't have a corresponding entry in the database (e.g. select ColumnA || Column B, 'SomeLiteral', 12 * ColumnC, null from MyTable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, and examine the results *(in the schemaTable table)*.

```
DataTable schemaTable;

String sql = "select * from ...";

using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnx))
  {
     cnx.Open();

     using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
     {
        schemaTable = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're taking an ad-hoc string, getting a DataTable, and trying to determine its datatype and length.

Try another approach by querying SQL Server directly. As you've discovered, DataColumn doesn't have all the info you need.

```
var cols = GetTableDetails("MyTable");  
DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromUserSpecifiedQuery(userSqlQuery);
foreach (var col in dt.Columns)
{
    var matching = cols.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name == col.ColumnName);   
    if (matching !=null)
    {
         //you now have the name, datatype, and length of the column
         //matched from your table. 
    }
}

public List<Col> GetTableDetails(string tableName)
{
    List<Col> cols = new List<Col>();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=Test1;Integrated Security=true;"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT syscolumns.name AS COLUMN_NAME, 
                                    systypes.name AS DATA_TYPE, 
                                    syscolumns.LENGTH AS LENGTH 
                            FROM       sysobjects 
                            INNER JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id 
                            INNER JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype = systypes.xtype 
                            WHERE     (sysobjects.xtype = 'U') and
                            sysobjects.name = @tableName
                            ORDER BY sysobjects.name, syscolumns.colid;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableName);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {                 
            cols.Add(new Col { Name= dr["COLUMN_NAME"],
                               DataType= dr["DATA_TYPE"],
                               Len = dr["LENGTH"] });                 
        }
        return cols;
    }
}


public class Col { 
  public string Name{get;set;} 
  public string DataType{get;set;} 
  public int Len{get;set;} 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I added text to the question explaining why this is not the solution I am looking for

Comment: @nine  You can work around the fact that it's a user query whose columns may not match the table. Take the user's adhoc query, and match against your table. All you really need is the table name. From there you can get a collection of datatype and length from SQL Server. No need to parse through the columns in the user string.